# SUPEE 6788 Error Applying Patch

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, html, supee-6788

I have applied all patches and also updated my .htaccess.sample to a stock magento file but the patch is not going successfully. I got this code.

```
            Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
            ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

            patching file .htaccess
            Hunk #1 FAILED at 207.
            1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file .htaccess.rej
            patching file .htaccess.sample
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
            patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php
            patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php
            patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
            patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
            patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
            patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
            patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
            patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
            patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
            patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
            patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
            patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
            patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
            patching file cron.php
            patching file errors/processor.php
            patching file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
            patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
            patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php
            patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
            patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php
            patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php
            patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php
            patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php
            patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
            patching file lib/Zend/Xml/Security.php
            patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
            Hunk #4 FAILED at 153.
            1 out of 4 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file lib/Zend/Xml/Security.php.rej
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sent you an email with the .htaccess and sample file.
As for the rest:

I'm not sure about those other files (lib/Unserialize) you get the error on now.. perhaps try removing them since the patch is attempting to create them.
For lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php back it up and try to replace with stock file since it appears to be edited.

Comment: Hi Anja, thanks!!! Inserting the htaccess files made the patch installed successfully. Now some layouts are missing. How can fix them?

Comment: the patch made it so all blocks need to be whitelisted. this guy made a toolbox which can automatically find all blocks you use and add them to the whitelist https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox . otherwise you can insert them manually via System > Permissions > Blocks

Comment: Since I used an older htaccess files, what happens to the previous patches  6285, 6482 etc. Do I need to re add them or they are no longer necessary? Also I scanned my site on magereport but its says SUPEE 6788 isn't installed any worries?

Comment: after patching you can replace the .htaccess file with your own (older) .htaccess file, and just add `###########################################
## Deny access to cron.php
    <Files cron.php>



############################################

        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all

    </Files>` since that's the only change it made to the .htaccess file

Comment: hm that didn't output well. I don't think you need to repatch the other patches. also I dunno why magereport says the patch isn't installed, it should say it's there

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup of .htaccess and lib/Zend/Xml/Security.php and change these files with originals that you can find in the release archive (https://www.magentocommerce.com/download), choosing your magento version. Apply again the patch :-)

Comment: Don't forget to manually apply any patches to the files you backup since there might be customizations in there.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have applied all previous security patches as some of them change the same files and the newer patches expect that version.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @serman I did as you said now I have this error message. I checked magereport but it still says patch not installed.

```
            Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
            ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

            patching file .htaccess
            Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
            Apply anyway? [n]
            Skipping patch.
            1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file .htaccess.rej
            patching file .htaccess.sample
            Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
            Apply anyway? [n]
            Skipping patch.
            1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file .htaccess.sample.rej
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
            patching file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
            patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php
            patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php
            patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
            patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
            patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
            patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
            patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
            patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
            patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
            patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
            patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
            patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
            patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
            patching file cron.php
            patching file errors/processor.php
            The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php,
            which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
            Apply anyway? [n]
            Skipping patch.
            1 out of 1 hunk ignored
            The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php,
            which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
            Apply anyway? [n]
            Skipping patch.
            1 out of 1 hunk ignored
            The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php,
            which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
            Apply anyway? [n]
            Skipping patch.
            1 out of 1 hunk ignored
            The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php,
            which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
            Apply anyway? [n]
            Skipping patch.
            1 out of 1 hunk ignored
            The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php,
            which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
            Apply anyway? [n]
            Skipping patch.
            1 out of 1 hunk ignored
            The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php,
            which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
            Apply anyway? [n]
            Skipping patch.
            1 out of 1 hunk ignored
            The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php,
            which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
            Apply anyway? [n]
            Skipping patch.
            1 out of 1 hunk ignored
            The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php,
            which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
            Apply anyway? [n]
            Skipping patch.
            1 out of 1 hunk ignored
            patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
            Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
            Apply anyway? [n]
            Skipping patch.
            2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php.rej
            patching file lib/Zend/Xml/Security.php
```

Comment: I think the .htaccess and .htaccess.sample from the stock download is also patched already, so you can't get a pre-patched .htaccess and .htaccess.sample.  I still have pre-patched files if you want them?

Comment: oh and those other files I probably have them as well, but it's from version 1.7.0.2.. not sure if that matters

Comment: Thank you Anja, can you please share them with me?

Comment: should I email you them? or just post the contents in an answer?